# UIImageView array

Tags: nsstring, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

How to put four images in a UIImageView array?
why my forloop can't run?

if i want to create four frames with four images,how to do that?

```
    NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],nil]; 




    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photos objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   }
```

Comment: Explain more. Do you want to use four images as animation?

Comment: if i add this forloop ,it will break down.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photos objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],nil]; 
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgView.animationImages = photos;
```

Comment: i want to set four images in four UIImageViews,not set animationImages.

Comment: It doesn't deserve answer for this: UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[photos objectAtIndex:0]]; or if you  already created imgView: imgView.image = [photos objectAtIndex:0]; but some googling no for this question?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photos objectAtIndex:i]];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
 }
 why this forloop can't work?

Comment: the scope of imageView is allocated only inside the for loop, after exit from the forloop the imageView is deallocated by ARC.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but i don't know how to modify it.can you teach me?

Answer (score 0):

`[photos objectAtIndex:i]` this method you get the UIImage object only , you can't get a NSString object for `[UIImage imageNamed:]` method.

Comment: is this the complete solution?